# Pintos installation SIGVTALRM() redefined error

Tags: operating-system, bochs, pintos

I got no error during installation, all make commands worked perfectly but in the end when I run "pintos run alarm-multiple", I'm getting the following error

```
Prototype mismatch: sub main::SIGVTALRM () vs none at /home/suhas/bin/pintos line 949.
Constant subroutine SIGVTALRM redefined at /home/suhas/bin/pintos line 941.
Writing command line to /tmp/k5qCPWWL5b.dsk...
squish-pty bochs -q
exec: No such file or directory
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple task. Just go to the file **/home/suhas/bin/pintos** and comment out the whole function `SIGVTALRM()`. It should work fine. Even I had the same error.